# how can i get an JSONObject from a json array

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am new to android programming and i would like to know how do i get a certain object from a JSONarray.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Contern",
           "short_name" : "Contern",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },

        {
           "long_name" : "Luxembourg",
           "short_name" : "Luxembourg",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },

        {
           "long_name" : "Luxembourg",
           "short_name" : "LU",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],

     "formatted_address" : "Contern, Luxembourg",

     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 49.621830,
              "lng" : 6.302790
           },

           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 49.56759010,
              "lng" : 6.195380
           }
        },

        "location" : {
           "lat" : 49.58515930,
           "lng" : 6.2274880
        },
```

and i want to extract the lat and lng from location.
my code is:

```
arr = json.getJSONArray("results");
        JSONObject location=arr.getJSONObject(4);
        double lng = location.getDouble("lng");
        double lat = location.getDouble("lat");
```

Comment: And what do you get now and what are expecting?

Comment: please post your whole json string.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to say that your json file is wrong but after closer look I think your code is bad :) I suppose it doesn't give you want you want now.
"results" in this case is JsonArray - but an array of full JsonObjects, not it's properties!
Full JsonObject is object with - address_components, format_address, geometry etc. "location" is also a part of "geometry" object.

When you are sure there will be only one object in "result" array - you can do:

```
arr = json.getJSONArray("results");
if (arr.length() > 0){
   JSONObject resultObject = arr.getJSONObject(0);
   JSONObject geometry = resultObject.getJSONObject("geometry");
   JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
   double lng = location.getDouble("lng");
   double lat = location.getDouble("lat");
}
```

When you have more than 1 object in result - I suppose you need to loop over them and find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Refer below code

JSON String

```
{
"result": "success",
"countryCodeList":
[
  {"countryCode":"00","countryName":"World Wide"},
  {"countryCode":"kr","countryName":"Korea"}
] 
}
```

Here below I am fetching country details

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONArray nameArray = json.names();
JSONArray valArray = json.toJSONArray(nameArray);

JSONArray valArray1 = valArray.getJSONArray(1);

valArray1.toString().replace("[", "");
valArray1.toString().replace("]", "");

int len = valArray1.length();

for (int i = 0; i < valArray1.length(); i++) {

 Country country = new Country();
 JSONObject arr = valArray1.getJSONObject(i);
 country.setCountryCode(arr.getString("countryCode"));                        
 country.setCountryName(arr.getString("countryName"));
 arrCountries.add(country);
}
```